# How to show my notes in this manner in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I'm a little new to Android and want to build a note taking app.

I'm figuring out all the tiny little things, but can't seem to figure out this,how can I show my data in this manner. **Please view image below.**

Should I use Recycler view,card view for this? I mean what's the proper views I should be using ?

I need a bit of proper direction.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank You.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0nna.jpg)

Comment: This looks like a `RecyclerView` that uses a `GridlayoutManager` and `CardView` for the individual views.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add GridlayoutManager:

```
// this in Activity, getContext() in Fragment
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridlayoutManager(this, 2));
```